# Вылет при выполнения + Box2D

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, box2d

При нажатии на кнопку "Старт", в консольке выскакивает ошибка, указывающую на один из заголовочных файлов Box2D, после чего компилятор начинает дико ругаться и вылетает. Подскажите, как возможно решить такую проблему.
Ошибка выскакивает с этого момента

```
if (player.START)
    {       
        World.Step(1.0f/60.0f, 10, 8);
```

и в консоли пишет:

> Assertion failed: 0<=index && index< m_count, file
>   D:...\Box2D/Collision/b2Distance.h, in line 103

Comment: Поставьте точку остановки в строчке 103 файла `b2Distance.h` и посмотрите отладчиком что там происходит, от куда берется некорректный `index`.

Comment: @Cerbo ,взглянула. Там index, как и m_count равен 0. Вылет происходит здесь:
`inline const b2Vec2& b2DistanceProxy::GetVertex(int32 index) const
{
 b2Assert(0 <= index && index < m_count);
 return m_vertices[index];
}`

Comment: Следовательно где-то запрашивается вершина с индексом 0, но количество вершин так же 0, правильно? Повторите исследование, но теперь, когда попадете на точку останова, посмотрите стек вызовов, что там до этого происходило и, главное, почему код считает что вершины есть, когда их, как видно, нет.

Comment: нашла ошибку. Как бы глупо это не звучало, но в заголовочном файле, где создается объект, нужно было поменять местами две строки. Первым должен идти SetAsBox, а второе - CreatureFixture